# round the number $a$ to $10^{-3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $2.12<x<2.13$ and I have $3.15<y<3.16$ and $a=y+xy+x$, round a to $10^{-3}$.

I have done using $xy$ multiplication then addition of $x$ then $y$ gotten this result $$11.948<a<12.0208$$ but $|11.948-12.0208|$ is not equal to $10^{-3}$.

So how can I do it?

thnxx

Comment: Interval arithmetic says $a=(3.15,3.16)+(2.12,2.13)\cdot(3.15,3.16)+(2.12,2.13)=(5.27,5.29)+(2.12\cdot 3.15, 2.13\cdot 3.16).$  Without multiplying all that out, you have $12.0208$ which is not rounded to $10^{-3}$...

Comment: The interval $(5.27,5.29)$ is wider than $10^{-3}$ so the required result is not possible, unless you are only required to specify an interval for $a$, in which case $a\in(11.948, 12.021)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to know whether $10^{-3}$ is relative or absolute error but your data doesn't support either one.

Answer (score 1):

You have errors $~0.01$. So you can't get an answer with error $~0.001$.
I have not checked your answer but if $$c \le \text{answer} \le d$$ then your answer is within
$$
\frac{c+d}{2} \pm \frac{d-c}{2}$$

You can round $\frac{c+d}{2} $ to 3 decimal places.

Comment: round number a to m means that if x<a<y is correct then |x-y| must equal m

Comment: no $|x-y| \le m$

Comment: we and you have different definition for what round a number is, i have gaved you the one that i use in school